# Rewrite jQuery function for updated HTML DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cheerio

Hi I'm looking to rewrite/update the `exportRound` JavaScript function which parses Jeopardy! round data from [j-archive.com](https://j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=7424) into a 'result' object that is consumed by rest of the program. It appears that the HTML tree structure has been updated since the function was originally written (not by me). Using Wayback machine, I'm able to get a previous HTM structure, for which this function works as expected

Function Definition

```
function exportRound ($, context, r) {
  var result = {};
  var round = $(r !== 'FJ' ? 'table.round' : 'table.final_round', context);

  // Export categories
  $('tr', round).first().children().each(function (i, element) {
    var data = $(this);
    result[['category', r, i + 1].join('_')] = {
      category_name: $('.category_name', data).text(),
      category_comments: $('.category_comments', data).text(),
      media: $('a', data).length ? $('a', data).map(function (i, element) {
        return $(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.j-archive.com/', 'http://localhost:3000/');
      }).toArray() : undefined
    };
  });

  // Export clues
  $('.clue_text', round).each(function (i, element) {
    var data = $(this);
    var header = data.parent().prev();
    if (r === 'FJ') {
      header = data.parent().parent().parent().parent().prev();
    }

    var answerHtml = _.trimLeft(_.trimRight($('div', header).attr('onmouseover'), ')'), 'toggle(').split(', ').slice(2).join(', ');
    answerHtml = _.trim(_.trim(answerHtml), '\'').replace('\\"', '"').replace('\\"', '"');
    var link = $('.clue_order_number a', header).attr('href');
    var daily_double = header.find('.clue_value_daily_double').length;

    result[data.attr('id')] = {
      id: link ? link.substring(link.indexOf('=') + 1, link.length) : undefined,
      daily_double: daily_double ? true : undefined,
      triple_stumper: _.contains(answerHtml, 'Triple Stumper') || undefined,
      clue_html: data.html(),
      clue_text: data.text(),
      correct_response: cheerio.load(answerHtml)('.correct_response').text(),
      media: $('a', data).length ? $('a', data).map(function (i, element) {
        return $(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.j-archive.com/', 'http://localhost:3000/');
      }).toArray() : undefined
    };
  });

  return result;
}
```

Old HTML Snippet

```
<td class="clue">
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      <div onmouseover="toggle('clue_J_5_1', 'clue_J_5_1_stuck', '<em class=&quot;correct_response&quot;>beam</em><br /><br /><table width=&quot;100%&quot;><tr><td class=&quot;right&quot;>Katrina</td></tr></table>')" onmouseout="toggle('clue_J_5_1', 'clue_J_5_1_stuck', 'A sturdy piece of timber, or a ray of sunshine')" onclick="togglestick('clue_J_5_1_stuck')">
        <table class="clue_header">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td id="clue_J_5_1_stuck" class="clue_unstuck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="clue_value">$200</td>
            <td class="clue_order_number"><a href="suggestcorrection.php?clue_id=432971" title="Suggest a correction for this clue" rel="nofollow">16</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="clue_J_5_1" class="clue_text">A sturdy piece of timber, or a ray of sunshine</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
    </td>
```

New HTML Snippet

```
<td class="clue">
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      <div onmouseover="toggle('clue_J_5_1', 'clue_J_5_1_r', 'clue_J_5_1_stuck')" onmouseout="toggle('clue_J_5_1_r', 'clue_J_5_1', 'clue_J_5_1_stuck')" onclick="togglestick('clue_J_5_1_stuck')">
        <table class="clue_header">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td id="clue_J_5_1_stuck" class="clue_unstuck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="clue_value">$200</td>
            <td class="clue_order_number"><a href="suggestcorrection.php?clue_id=432971" title="Suggest a correction for this clue" rel="nofollow">16</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="clue_J_5_1" class="clue_text" style="display: table-cell;">A sturdy piece of timber, or a ray of sunshine</td>
    <td id="clue_J_5_1_r" class="clue_text" style="display: none;"><em class="correct_response">beam</em><br><br><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="right">Katrina</td></tr></tbody></table></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
    </td>
```

I've been reading up on using jQuery on traversing HTML structures, but did not get very far.

I've added a `.not('[id$="_r"]')` selector which prevented selection of the responses as a separate clue, however I tried using the `.next()` selector on the data variable to try to get to the responses, but that did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The old answer appears to be baked right into the `mouseover` attribute, but now it's been moved to `.correct_response`. Much easier: `correct_response: data.find(".correct_response")?.text()`.